# Display data from multiple select statements

Tags: sql

I was trying to display some data from the EMP table, the output that I would like to achieve is the following:

```
ENAME, SUM_SAL, AVG(SAL),MAX(SAL)
```

The problem i that I would need to add a where clause on each group function, for example:

```
SELECT ENAME, (SELECT SUM(COMM) FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500) ,SELECT (AVG(COMM) FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500), GROUP BY ENAME
```

This doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work how? Describe, and also give sample data and desired output!

Comment: Are the aggregate column values intended to be the same for every employee?

Answer (score 1):

To get aggregation based on each employee name write as:

```
 SELECT ENAME,
        SUM(COMM),
        AVG(COMM)
 FROM EMP
 WHERE EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500
 GROUP BY ENAME
```

To get aggregation based on employees in the table write as:

```
 SELECT ENAME,
        SUM(COMM) OVER (ORDER BY EMPNO ASC) as sum_sal,
        AVG(COMM) OVER (ORDER BY EMPNO ASC) as avg_sal,
        MAX(COMM) OVER (ORDER BY EMPNO ASC) as MAX_sal
 FROM @EMP
 WHERE EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT ENAME,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500 THEN COMM
             ELSE 0
           END) [Sum],
       Avg(CASE
             WHEN EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500 THEN COMM
           END) [Avg]
FROM   EMP
GROUP  BY ENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
SELECT ENAME, SUM(COMM), AVG(COMM)
FROM EMP
WHERE EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500
GROUP BY ENAME
```

It will select every `ENAME` with `EMPNO` between 7000 and 7500 and, for each of them get the sum and average of `COMM`.

Answer (score 0):

The values the sum and average are constant (they don't vary with the employee), but your query (and other answers so far) calculate them over again for every employee.

Instead of trying to do it on the fly per employee, calculate the aggregates *once*, then simply join to the result:

```
SELECT ENAME, SUM_COMM, AVG_COMM, MAX_COMM
FROM (SELECT SUM(COMM) SUM_COMM, AVG(COMM) AVG_COMM, MAX(COMM) MAX_COMM
    FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO BETWEEN 7000 AND 7500) X
CROSS JOIN EMP
```

This has the added advantage of one pass to collect all aggregate values and one WHERE clause;, which should perform really well.